# Accidentally set password without encrypting

Tags: ssh, password, password-recovery

I accidentally change password in ubuntu without encrypt it first. With command

```
usermod --password PASSWORD USERNAME
```

How can I know the password string?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot recover the password. `usermod` has a poor description of this command as the password isn't encrypted, but hashed and salted. The intention it's impractical to recover the password from the hash, when using this information can easily be collected from your bash history.

If you still have admin access, use the `passwd` command to change the password:

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

If not, but you have physical access, you can use [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) as described in Ubuntu wiki to drop to a root shell, where you can change the password as described above.